# Snowflake sql is updating all rows instead of selective rows from WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to update only certain rows of table1 where source='abc'. However, it ends up updating all the rows of table1 as if WHERE clause doesn't exist. I want to update a column from another table's column value where the IDs are same between the two tables

```
UPDATE table1 
SET col1 = table2.col2
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.ID=table2.ID
WHERE table1.source='abc'
```

I'm running the above query on Snowflake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct UPDATE syntax is:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET col1 = table2.col2
FROM table2 
WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID
  AND table1.source = 'abc';
```